# Authors names at the beginning of article

Tags: titles, amsart

I am trying to submit an article to a journal that requires the authors' names and contact information to be stated right after the title of the article. I am using the amsart style, and the default setting for this style is to list the contact information at the end of the article. Since I would prefer not to change styles, any suggestions as to how to list the contact information with the authors names at the beginning of the article would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the journal offer or suggest a particular LaTeX style or template? If so, you should use it. Generally you don't get to pick your own style to submit to a journal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't accept my answer? Did it not solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments: if the journal offers or suggests a particular LaTeX style or template, then you should use it. Generally you don't get to pick your own style to submit to a journal.

In the `amsart` class the contact information is typeset with the command `\enddoc@text`. You can use that command right after `\maketitle` to get the contact information right after the title:

```
\maketitle

\makeatletter
\enddoc@text
\let\enddoc@text\empty % to remove the contact info from the end of the document
\makeatother
```

Note that we need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to be able to use `\enddoc@text`, because it contains an `@`. We do `\let\enddoc@text\empty` to remove the contact information from the end of the document.

A full example with some formatting:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Author \and Author}
\title{Title}
\address{University of bla}
\email{bla@bla.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\makeatletter
\vspace{-2em}
{\centering\enddoc@text}
\let\enddoc@text\empty % to remove the contact info from the end of the document
\makeatother

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[50]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```